# Save canvas to dir on server not working

Tags: php, html, canvas, sign

I have a script that let people sign a document by a HTML5 Canvas. I want to save the signature on a specified Directory. But somehow I can't get this to work.

**Sign.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Signature Pad demo</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Signature Pad - HTML5 canvas based smooth signature drawing using variable width spline interpolation.">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Core/CSS/signature-pad.css">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-39365077-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

    function loadDoc() {
        // create a dataUrl from the canvas
        var dataURL= canvas.toDataURL();

        // post the dataUrl to php

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "upload.php",
            data: {image: dataURL}
        }).done(function( respond ) {
            // you will get back the temp file name
            // or "Unable to save this image."
            console.log(respond);
        });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onselectstart="return false">
  <a id="github" href="https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad">
    <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_right_gray_6d6d6d.png" alt="Fork me on GitHub">
  </a>

  <div id="signature-pad" class="m-signature-pad">
    <div class="m-signature-pad--body">
      <canvas></canvas>
    </div>

    <div class="m-signature-pad--footer">
      <div class="description">Sign above</div>
      <button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
      <button type="button" class="button save" onclick="loadDoc()">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="Core/Scripts/signature_pad.js"></script>
  <script src="Core/Scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Save.php**

```
<?php

// make sure the image-data exists and is not empty
// xampp is particularly sensitive to empty image-data 
if ( isset($_POST["image"]) && !empty($_POST["image"]) ) {    

    // get the dataURL
    $dataURL = $_POST["image"];  

    // the dataURL has a prefix (mimetype+datatype) 
    // that we don't want, so strip that prefix off
    $parts = explode(',', $dataURL);  
    $data = $parts[1];  

    // Decode base64 data, resulting in an image
    $data = base64_decode($data);  

    // create a temporary unique file name
    $file = 'uploads/' . uniqid() . '.png';

    // write the file to the upload directory
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

    // return the temp file name (success)
    // or return an error message just to frustrate the user (kidding!)
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save this image.';

}
```

Both files are in the same directory.
The uploads directory is a sub directory like this:

```
Web
|-uploads (directory)
|-Handtekening.php (Sign.php)
|-upload.php (Save.php)
```

Comment: "some how I can't get is to work" is an insufficient problem description. What happens if you run your code and in how far that differs from your expectation? Make sure you have read and understood [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: These are the file as the are on the server. If i open the 'Handtekening.php' I get a canvas to sign then when i click save nothing happen

Comment: I'm sure they are. Still, "But somehow I can't get this to work." is not a sufficient problem description. I'm trying to help, since this is your first post here and I am advising you to provide a suffient problem description if you are interested in getting answers to your question.

Comment: Sorry for my bad description. The problem is after te sign is made the use need to press the save button. But when de Save button is clickes nothing happens. so it looks like the Save action won't be done